# TeamViewer as a client, to connect to a Windows machine

Tags: teamviewer

I mean to connect from my Ubuntu 20.04.05LTS to a Windows machine with TeamViewer.
I have just installed the .deb for TeamViewer.
It only shows as TeamViewer Host, and when I launch it, it doesn't look like I was used to.

[image]

I don't see how to use it as a client, where I can simply enter the information for the server and connect to it.

Is that possible? How?

Comment: FYI:  A fully upgraded Ubuntu 20.04 LTS system will report itself as 20.04.6 and not 20.04.5, so ensure you've applied all security fixes & patches if your machine is online.  You can refer to https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2023/03/23/ubuntu-20-04-6-lts-released/ for the ISO release date, but installed systems upgraded in the week before that date.

Comment: @guiverc - I fixed 22 -> 20 in the OP. And I will check what you mention. OTOH, I hardly think it is related to any hint to my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Download and install TeamViewer Remote

It looks like you have installed the TeamViewer **Host**. Uninstall it. Go back to the [TeamViewer Download Linux](https://www.teamviewer.com/en/download/linux/) page. You will see something like:

[image]

Download and install the **TeamViewer Remote for Linux**. Do not download the TeamViewer Host in the bottom half of the page. I have crossed it out in red.

##### Personal Opinion below

I personally like AnyDesk as it has a smaller footprint and works very similarly, but either will do the job as long as the Windows machine has the corresponding app installed.

Hope this helps

Comment: For some reason, I missed that part of the webpage (which is at the top!).
I don't know if I scrolled too fast, or it was not showing because of some filter (unlikely).